# yii urlmanager not working for get attributes

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I am new to yii. My urlmanager is not changing the get params...here is code of
yiicode/protected/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',


                      'rules'=>array(

                            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
    ),
```

view code

```
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
$params=array('city'=>'london');
$route='site/index';
$ur=$this->createUrl($route,$params);
```

html

```
<a href="<?php echo $ur;"?> >Click here to check London hotels</a>
```

on clik it goes to url /yiicode/index.php/site/index?city=london instead of /yiicode/index.php/site/index/city/london

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add rule like this.

```
'rules'=>array(
            'site/index/city/<city:.*?>'=>'site/index',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

add such rule:    `'site/index/city/<city:.*?>'=>'site/index'`